# React: Getting undefined when handling error response in Axios

Tags: php, reactjs, error-handling, axios, undefined

I'm trying to handle error responses from a api call, but when i get error status in browser like 404 or 403. It seems like i can't console.log error.responses. I'm using PHP for back-end, but i'm unsure if it's a problem from back-end or front-end.

Front-End code:

```
async function getData() {
    await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASEURL}/test/`,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        "Authorization": `Bearer #####`
      },
      data: {
        test: test
      }
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        // Error
        if (error.response) {
          // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
          // that falls out of the range of 2xx
          // console.log(error.response.data);
          console.log(error.response.status);
          console.log(error.headers);
          console.log(error.response);
        } else if (error.request) {
          // The request was made but no response was received
          // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the 
          // browser and an instance of
          // http.ClientRequest in node.js
          console.log(error.request);
        } else {
          // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
          console.log('Error', error.message);
        }
        //console.log(error.config);
      })
  }
```

Back-end code snip (What i'm sending in response):

```
$error = 403;
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    http_response_code($error);
    print json_encode(array('status'=> $error), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

However, if i try to console.log(error.response) i get undefined. Any reason why?

Comment: Have You checked developer tools network? Do you see the expected request/response there?

Comment: I do see this in this console.log: Request of cross origin was blocked: The Same Origin policy does not allow reading of the external resource at https://test-api.no/post/. (Cause: CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is missing). Status code: 403. Which is right, however i'm not able to access the status code in react. In developer tools network, I do also get: Response body is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS Missing Allow Origin).

Comment: Then you got your answer: the reason why your axios client does not get the response is because the browser is blocking it because of the CORS headers.